# JAXB XJC Suppress ObjectFactory & Generate jaxb.index

Tags: java, ant, jaxb, xjc

I have a large number of Generated Classes in my project that are generated using an `xjc` ant task. By default, the generation process creates an `ObjectFactory.java` class. I was wondering if there was a way to suppress the creation of ObjectFactory and instead generate a `jaxb.index` file.

My understanding is that jaxb.index is more optimal than ObjectFactory for object serialization & deserialization.

I'm working with **Ant 1.10.3** & **JAXB 2.3.0**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a warning: make sure you know what you do. `ObjectFactory` has a few features (like supporting substitution groups) which `jaxb.index` does not have. So suppressing `ObjectFactory` may lead to not being able to parse valid XML.

Now, assuming you know what you do, how to do it.

[JAXB2 Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) includes a "JAXB Index" plugin which generates `jaxb.index`. Usage in Ant would be something like:

```
    <xjc destdir="${basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc" extension="true">
        <arg line="
            -Xjaxbindex"/>
        <binding dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources">
            <include name="**/*.xjb"/>
        </binding>
        <schema dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources">
            <include name="**/*.xsd"/>
        </schema>
        <!-- Plugins -->
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
                <!-- JAXB2 Basics library -->
                <include name="jaxb2-basics-plugins-*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </xjc>
```

To suppress `ObjectFactory`, simply delete the generated file.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics). I am not sure wether it works with JAXB 2.3.0.